# Working with bitmaps - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

I have implemented a ViewPager which will hold 5 BitMap's. My images are not bigger than 50kb each. When the ViewPager is initialized, first 2 image is instantiated but the memory they consume is 100 MB! After second image my app consumes around 256MB of memory, which is 190MB more than my normal memory usage. That happens only after 3 image creation. (Total 150KB)

I tried decoding BitMaps but did not work. I have no idea why such a small image consumes that much of memory. Image slide animations are normally soo sluggish. Do you have any idea where I'm doing wrong?

Log

```
Initialize start
﹕ Position 0 is created
﹕ Position 1 is created
 Initialize end
Swipe Next image (1)
﹕ Position 2 is created
Swipe Next image (2)
﹕ Position 0 is destroyed
﹕ Position 3 is created
Swipe Next image (3)
﹕ Position 1 is destroyed
﹕ Position 4 is created
Swipe Next image (4)(last image)
﹕ Position 2 is destroyed
Swipe Previous image (3)
﹕ Position 2 is created
Swipe Previous image (2)
CRASHED
```

**Here is my Adapter**

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        DebugLog.debug(TAG,"Position " + position + " is created");
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, collection, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mResources[position]);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        collection.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View)object;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        if (bmpDrawable != null && bmpDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            bmpDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
            DebugLog.debug(TAG, "Position " + position + " is destroyed");
        }
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        view = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bitmap holds an uncompressed image and requires 3 or 4 (with alpha)  bytes per pixel. So, even if your image (jpg, png, ...) is small, it still may be huge, when uncompressed.

Comment: 32 bit * x px * y px, AT LEAST.

Comment: I configured the sampleSize to 2 before decoding and it seems to consume less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your adapter
     private HashMap usedImages;

```
 ...
 public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
   ...
    usedImages=new HashMap<>();
  }

  @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    DebugLog.debug(TAG,"Position " + position + " is created");
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, collection, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mResources[position]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    usedImages.put(position, bitmap);          
    collection.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}


 @Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    View view = (View)object;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    Bitmap bitmap = usedImages.get(position);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
     }

    usedImages.remove(position);
    container.removeView(view);
}
```

Add method **clear()** to your adapter and call it in **onDestroy**  of activity or fragment :

```
public void clear(){
    if(usedImages!=null) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Bitmap> item : usedImages.entrySet()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = item.getValue();
            if (bitmap != null) {
              bitmap.recycle();
              bitmap = null;
             }
        }
        usedImages.clear();
        usedImages = null;
    }
  mContext = null;
  mLayoutInflater=null;

}
```

Comment: I applied your method to recycle the used images but it still does not free up the memory used by the images